# Negative binomial dispersion parameter in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, poisson, mixture-model, gamma-distribution

The matlab function `nbinfit` returns the values `r` and `p` for the negative binomial. Is there an equivalent MLE function in matlab that instead returns the values for mu (mean) and theta (the dispersion parameter) for the "ecological" or "Polya" parametrization of the negative binomial?

(something like `fitdistr` in R)

Comment: I don't know of such a function and I don't know enough about the problem to say if you can directly convert between the two parameterizations or not. You may need to implement your own MLE function for this in Matlab. I'd suggest that you ask a slightly different form of this question at [Stats.StackExchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com). You might ask if it's possible to convert the result from Matlab's `nbinfit` to the parameters you want. And/or you could ask the MLE for the ecological parametrization. Look at the source for R's `fitdistr` and see if you can translate it to Matlab.